# facebook app keeps the input field form values when going back

Tags: html, css, facebook

I am building a facebook app ....

Lets say you fill up the form after clicking like button. You get a thank you page. Now go back using browser back button. Most of the input data values still remains. That is a problem. How to make sure that when user goes back the values not there?

http://on.fb.me/1iyj6ZQ

Comment: That's the browser back button. It just works like that. Maybe you can try the autocomplete attribute but not sure if it will work.

Comment: I think the autocomplete works. Though will need to test fully before I can say it is solved. But seems so far working

Comment: You could just `reset` the form on page load …